# Calculate residuals but from other slope and intercept in R

Tags: r

Here I have two dataframes called `model1` and `model2`:

```
class1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
abund1<-c(10.4,8.9,9.1,7.5,7.1,5.1,3.2)
model1<-data.frame(class1,abund1)
class2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
abund2<-c(9.5,8.4,8,6.3,6,2.4,1.2)
model2<-data.frame(class2,abund2)
```

Firstly, I use `lm` to extract the slope and intercept for the `model1`:

```
model1_lm<-lm(abund1~class1, data=model1)
model1_lm$coefficients[1]
11.7857                    #intercept from the model1
model1_lm$coefficients[2]
-1.1143                    #slope from the model1
```

What I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the residuals (i.e. ovserved value - predicted value) for the plot `class2-abund2` from `model2` but using the slope and intercept from `model1`.

Here I show you the graphs for both models with the same slope and intercept from the model1:

[image]

**My purpose would be to calculate the residuals in the model2 but, as you may see, the slope and intercept come from the model1**.

Hope to be clear and any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `predict` with the fitted model and `model2` as your new data:

```
# predict will look for a column called "class1" in the newdata argument, so we need to provide it.
# observed - predicted
model2$abund2 - predict(model1_lm, data.frame(class1 = model2$class2))
#         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
#-1.1714286 -1.1571429 -0.4428571 -1.0285714 -0.2142857 -2.7000000 -2.7857143
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank! I thought that it was much more difficult but I didn't know the function predict

Comment: @Rinot Reading the help file for `lm` would help you.